# How to expect varying number of whitespaces sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to parse a big proxy txt file (i.e, file with proxy information (ip,port,protocol...)) using sscanf and I've come to the problem where there are ip addresses that are not of the same lenght leaves the line with varying whitespaces as shown in the example:

```
72.210.221.197  4145    Socks5  United States   Elite   932ms   93.8%   10 minutes
176.98.90.20    8080    HTTP    Ukraine Elite   183ms   77.3%   4 minutes
```

There are 2 whitespaces in the first line between ip and port and in second 4 whitespaces. Since %s reads until the whitespace, is there a way for sscanf to ignore all the whitespaces?

Comment: Since you can't use absolute positions or read a certain numbers of fields, I suggest reformatting the file. Putting the country name last should make it easier to parse.

Comment: What did you try so far? Where is your code? What problem do you have with that code? BTW it will be much easier to write function splitting and trimming. `scanf` is to too good for this task

Comment: Your bigger problem is you have whitespace embedded in your actual data (`"United States"`...), but you're using whitespace as the a delimiter.

Comment: The format is unparseable.

Comment: @TedLyngmo formatting the IP addresses as XX.XX.XX.XX hex representations would also reduce inconsistency of spacing.

Comment: post a bit of the input file. Help others helps you

Comment: you just need a parser for this file, and it is trivial, since it seems to be a line oriented file with 8 fields per line

Answer (score 1):

A very simple implementation of the the function:

```
char **split(char **argv, int *argc, const char *str, const char *delimiter, int allowempty)
{
    char *string = malloc(strlen(str + 1));
    strcpy(string, str);
    *argc = 0;
    do
    {
        if(*string && (!strchr(delimiter, *string) || allowempty))
        {
            argv[(*argc)++] = string;
        }
        while(*string && !strchr(delimiter, *string)) string++;
        if(*string) *string++ = 0;
        if(!allowempty) 
            while(*string && strchr(delimiter, *string)) string++;
    }while(*string);

    for(int arg = 3; arg < *argc - 5 - 1; arg++)
    {
        argv[3][strlen(argv[3])] = ' ';
        memmove(&argv[4], &argv[arg + 2], sizeof(*argv) * (*argc - 4));
        *argc -= 1;
    }
    return argv;
}



int main(void)
{
    char *argv[20];
    char str[1024];
    int argc;

    while(fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin))
    {
        split(argv, &argc, str, " ", 0);
        for(int arg = 0; arg < argc; arg++)
        {
            printf("arg[%d] = `%s`\n", arg, argv[arg]);
        }
        free(*argv);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

And for your input, it is giving:

```
arg[0] = `72.210.221.197`
arg[1] = `4145`
arg[2] = `Socks5`
arg[3] = `United States`
arg[4] = `Elite`
arg[5] = `932ms`
arg[6] = `93.8%`
arg[7] = `10`
arg[8] = `minutes
`

arg[0] = `176.98.90.20`
arg[1] = `8080`
arg[2] = `HTTP`
arg[3] = `Ukraine`
arg[4] = `Elite`
arg[5] = `183ms`
arg[6] = `77.3%`
arg[7] = `4`
arg[8] = `minutes`
```

PS it can written better but hangover is prohibiting my brain form too complicated maths

Answer (score 0):

When one looks closely at the two sample lines, it appears that this is a TSV... A Tab Separated Value list... If the file does contain tabs, chopping out the individual fields would be a trivial use of `strtok()`. (`scanf()` processes *whitespace*. Any such implementation would be arcane.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    // simulate two lines of fgets() input
    char *strs[] = {
        "72.210.221.197\t4145\tSocks5\tUnited States\tElite\t932ms\t93.8%\t10 minutes\n",
        "176.98.90.20\t8080\tHTTP\tUkraine\tElite\t183ms\t77.3%\t4 minutes\n",
    };

    for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof strs / sizeof strs[0]; i++ ) {
        char *flds[ 8 ];
        size_t nf = 0;

        for( char *cp = strs[i]; ( cp = strtok( cp, "\t\n" ) ) != NULL; cp = NULL )
            flds[ nf++] = cp;

        for( size_t j = 0; j < nf; j++ )
            printf( "'%s'\n", flds[ j ] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
'72.210.221.197'
'4145'
'Socks5'
'United States'
'Elite'
'932ms'
'93.8%'
'10 minutes'

'176.98.90.20'
'8080'
'HTTP'
'Ukraine'
'Elite'
'183ms'
'77.3%'
'4 minutes'
```

Simple solutions are the best solutions.